# Themeable Browser is not working on chrome simulator

Tags: cordova, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I am trying to use Themeable Browser on chrome but it display warninh in console.
**Native: Themeable Browser is not installed or you are running on a browser.
Falling back to window.open**

So any other option like Themeable browser which can work on chrome simulator also.

Answer (score 0):

Themeable Browser is a native plugin, you can't test native plugins in Chrome.

There are no options like Themeable browser for Chrome, you should test your Cordova apps in a real device on in an Android simulator